# Lambda Times Out Writing to DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple function that puts an item into the database.  I have enabled a role that has a policy attached to allow puts for this table.
Here is the code below.  I have even tired hard coding all the information still it times out.  I have also tried increasing the timeout to 30 seconds and the Memory to 512 MB but it still just times out.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const AWS = require(`aws-sdk`);
AWS.config.update({region: `eu-east-2`});
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

   
   var TableName ="MyFirstExamAnswers";
   var Item = {};
  
    Item["Student"] = event.params.Student;
    Item[event.params.Question] = event.params.Answer;
    console.log("theItem: "+ JSON.stringify( Item));
 
    dynamo.put({TableName,Item}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`error`, err);
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            var response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': `GET,POST,OPTIONS`,
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `*`,
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': `true`
               },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                isBase64Encoded: false
            };
            console.log(`success: returned ${data.Item}`);
           
           callback(null, response);
       }
    });
    
};
```

With the following policy attached to the role that the Lambda is running under

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowDBAccess2Lambda001",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:MyAccountNumber:table/MyFirstExamAnswers"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is your lambda function running in a VPC?

Comment: If your Lambda is in a VPC, you can add a VPC endpoint for DynamoDB and you’ll be set: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html

Comment: No it is not running in a VPC.